# R: Equivalent of "rank" and "partition"

Tags: sql, r, duplicates, odbc, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I have the following SQL query:

```
select b.var1 as var1, b.var2 from
(select *, rank() over( partition by var1 order by var3) as rank1
from my_table)b;
```

The goal of this SQL code is to:

- Find groups of records containing duplicate values of the same "var1"
- For each of these groups, sort these records based on their values of "var3"
- For each of these groups of sorted duplicate records, only keep the the record with the largest value of "var3"
- Note: Records containing non-duplicate values of "var1" are left untouched

**My Question:** Does anyone know if it is possible to run this same code in R? For example:

```
library(RODBC)
library(dbi)
library(odbc)
library(sqldf)
library(SQLite)

dbWriteTable(my_db_connection, SQL("   select b.var1 as var1, b.var2 from
    (select *, rank() over( partition by var1 order by var3) as rank1
    from my_table)b " ), results_of_this_query)
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this in R? Does R recognize SQL commands like "rank()", "over" and "partition"?

Thanks!

Comment: If my_table is a data frame in R then `library(sqldf); sqldf("...")` will process it where "..." is a character string containing an SQL statement involving my_table.  By default it uses SQLite as the backend but 3 other back ends are also supported.  Note the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page about asking questions and in particular questions should include the input, here my_table, and should be shown using dput so others can run the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `ave` with `rank` after you sort by partition and order columns:

```r
df <- with(df, df[order(var1, var3),])

df$rank1 <- with(df, ave(var3, var1, FUN=rank))
```

Add lambda for other arguments:

```
df$rank1 <- with(df, ave(var3, var1, FUN=function(x) rank(x, ties.method="first", na.last="keep")))
```

Comment: @ Parfait : Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to use your answer with the "dbWriteTable" command? For example:  dbWriteTable(my_db_connection, SQL(" with(df, ave(1:nrow(df), var2, FUN=function(x) rank(x, ties.method="first", na.last="keep"))) " ), results_of_this_query) ? Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm...why not directly run SQL?

Answer (score 1):

The [Tidyverse collection of packages](https://www.tidyverse.org/) specially the [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) can easy do this task for you on a grammar likely SQL.

The final code should be something like

```
df %>%
group_by(var1) %>%
mutate(rank = dense_rank(var3))
```

I may not understand you SQL-string and made the correctly translated because SQL language is not my strong skill.

Comment: @ Gregory Oliveira : Thank you for your answer! Would it be possible to use your answer along with the dbWriteTable() command? For example: dbWriteTable(my_db_connection, SQL("   df %>%
group_by(var1) %>%
mutate(rank = dense_rank(var3)) " ), results_of_this_query) ? Thanks!

Comment: @stats555, I will try later. I need to recap some importing taks with SQL and then I will provide you the code. See you later!